# Run-time error: cannot import name py31compat

Tags: python, numpy, compilation

Have a compiled app that fails when multiarray attempts to import py31compat.  It runs fine from source.

I am using Anaconda2-4.4.0-Windowsx86_64.exe (windows 7)
Using numpy-1.12.1, which was installed with pip

Compiling with py2exe script.

The error it gives is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AutoFastener.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "BatchControl\modBatchController.pyo", line 94, in <module>
  File "FastenerDataSetUtilities\modFDDUtils.pyo", line 21, in <module>
  File "scipy\__init__.pyo", line 61, in <module>
  File "numpy\__init__.pyo", line 180, in <module>
  File "numpy\add_newdocs.pyo", line 13, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyo", line 8, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\type_check.pyo", line 11, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\__init__.pyo", line 23, in <module>
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
cannot import name py31compat
```

I've tried upgrading setuptools and distribute with pip, which did not help.

I've looked in the executables LIB file, and the pkg_resources has py31compat.pyo in it, which as far as I've been able to determine is where it should be.

I don't know how to figure out where the multiarray.pyd is trying to load it from.